# If $\textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then show that the following inequalities hold.

Tags: vectors, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

If $\textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then show that the following inequalities hold

$||\textbf{x}||_\infty \leq ||\textbf{x}||_2 \leq \sqrt{n}||\textbf{x}||_\infty$

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}||\textbf{x}||_1 \leq ||\textbf{x}||_2 \leq \sqrt{n}||\textbf{x}||_1$

---

I have been trying to read about $L^\infty$ spaces and not sure if this translates to vector norms. I read that a vector norm is the max entry value. I would like some help on a definition of the terms shown above and how to being this problem. I have tried to think about how an infinite vector could possibly have an entry with larger value than a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I am not sure if I am even on the right track in thinking about this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for definitions, in the finite dimensional space $\mathbb R^n$, if $\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^n$ with coordinates $x_i$, for $1 \leqslant i \leqslant n$
\begin{align}
\lVert \mathbf x \rVert_\infty &= \max_{1 \leqslant i \leqslant n} \lvert x_i \rvert \\ 
\lVert \mathbf x \rVert_2 &= \sqrt {\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^2 }\\
\lVert \mathbf x \rVert_1 &= \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|.
\end{align}
The inequalities you state then follow pretty directly from these definitions.

The concepts also extend to *infinite* dimensions.  There are three vector spaces that correspond to those above.

The first, written $\ell_\infty$ is the space of all bounded sequences $x_i, 1 \leqslant i$ in which the norm is defined as $\lVert \mathbf x \rVert_\infty = \sup_{1 \leqslant i} | x_i |$.  The supremum exists because the sequence must be bounded to be contained in the space $\ell_\infty$.

A few examples:  the sequence $(x_i) = (1,2,3,4,\cdots)$ is not in $\ell_\infty$ because it is unbounded.  The two sequences $(1,1,1,\cdots)$ and $(1,1/2,1/3,\cdots)$ are both in $\ell_\infty$ because they are bounded.  Both have $\ell_\infty$ norm of $1$.

The second space is $\ell_2$ with corresponding norm $\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_i|^2}$, where members of the space are required to have finite norm.  Of the three sequences above, only the last is in $\ell_2$ with norm $\pi/\sqrt 6$,as the norms of the other two would be infinite, thereby disqualifying the sequences from inclusion in the space $\ell_2$.

The third, $\ell_1$ has norm $\sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_i|$, and none of the three examples are in the space because all there have unbounded norms.